# Given $ \int_a^b{\phi(t)dt} = C $ find an expression for $b$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

If I am given, where $\phi$ is monotonic and has an inverse:

$$ \int_a^b{\phi(t)dt} = C $$

Is it possible to find an expression for $b$?

So far I have tried the following. Let

$$\frac{d}{dt}\psi(t) = \phi(t)$$
$$\psi^{-1}(f) = \phi^{-1}\left(\frac{d}{dt}f\right)$$

So expressing the definite integral as indefinite integrals
$$ \int_a^b{\phi(t)dt} = \psi(b) - \psi(a) = C $$
$$ b = \psi^{-1}(C + \psi(a)) $$
$$ b = \phi^{-1}\left(\frac{d}{dt}C + \phi(a)\right) $$

But this doesn't seem right to me given that C is a constant and therefore $b = a$. Is this because I can't actually find an inverse $\psi^{-1}$?

I'm really keen on making my maths more rigorous so please go into as much depth as you like.

Comment: There's not necessarily a unique answer. For instance if $a=0$, $C=0$, and $\phi(t)=\sin(t)$ then there are infinitely many solutions $b=2\pi k$, $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: From what you wrote, you cannot ensure that $\phi$ has an inverse. Are you giving us all the hypothesis you have ? And, as the other comment already pointed out, a non-monotonic $\phi$ can lead to multiple answers.

Comment: Sorry, I have assumed $\phi$ has an inverse. I have updated the question accordingly. @nicomezi What do you mean by the hypothesis I have?

Comment: I think you have to make another assumption on $\phi$, for example requiring it to be positive.

Comment: I think my step with the inverse of $\psi$ is wrong since d/dt is an operator on a function whereas $\phi^{-1}$ is a function, for instance from R->R.

Comment: If, e.g., $\phi(t)=t$ $\>(t\in{\mathbb R})$  then $\int_{-2}^{-1}\phi(t)\>dt=\int_{-2}^1\phi(t)\>dt=-{3\over2}$. This shows that $b$ is not determined by the given data $t\mapsto\phi(t)$, $a$, and $C$.